# Start app when install finishes

Tags: android, mobile-application

I want my app to start its business as soon as it's installed. I couldn't ind any docs on this, but I think I remember seeing apps do it in the past.

Details:
The use case is for users with dead screens to download the app using the play store website in order to access their phone data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want my app to start its business as soon as it's installed

That is not possible anymore, as of Android 3.1, sorry.